# Cucumber JVM: How to access data from Examples section in hooks with scenario outline?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am using cucumber JVM, I have below scenario outline:

```
 Scenario Outline:
    Given a user login in as <username>
    When the user login
    Then welcome message shoule show to <username>

 Examples:
   | username |
   | alice    |
   | bob      |
   | steve    |
```

I want to access the data from scenario hooks, for example:

```
@Before
public void beforeScenario() {
  List<String> headers = examples.getHeaders()
  String header = headers.filter(header -> header.equals("username")).findFirst().get();
  example.get(header); // should be alice, bob, steve in sequence
}
```

Above code for hooks is not working, is it possible to access the Example table from hooks? if it's possible, how to do it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The `@Before` hook is executed before each scenario execution. Means it is executed once for alice, bob, steve. Why do you want/need in each scenario execution access to **all** outline examples?

Comment: @SubOptimal, I need to handle some special test data, which has a strong relationship with the username in each scenario, actually, I don't have to access all outline examples, if I am able to access the one that currently executing is also ok. Thanks.

Comment: If it's something which is related to the test itself, I would add it to a scenario step, e.g. `Given handle test data for <username>` and `And a user login in as <username>`. Could this work for you as well?

Comment: Yes, that should work. :). I am still curious if it's possible to do it hooks in cucumber JVM, from the learning perspective.

Comment: It's not foreseen out of the box. A hacky way would be to pass the scenario object to the method `public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario)` and parse the feature file yourself, based on the information. `scenario.getUri())` gives you the path to the feature file and with `scenario.getLines()` you get the line of the `Scenario Outline:` and the current line in `Examples:`.

Comment: Your idea is cool, thanks very much.